# Finding a software engineering job in Switzerland as a non EU citizen

Tags: working-visas, eu, switzerland

So I'm an intermediate software developer currently working in Canada and I want to know how doable finding a job, which in turn means finding an employer that is willing to support you for all the visa process, in Switzerland is.

I'm guessing if one has super special skills things would be easier as the employer can prove that the skill is required and currently non existent in the country, but that's not the case for me. So please answer my question assuming I'm just above average in terms of skills in software development.

Is it worth trying or the chances or low and if it's doable, what's the best way to find an employer, through an agency, linkedin, etc. ?

Comment: If you want to live in Geneva you might want to look at jobs with the UN, although I don't know how many software jobs they have there.

Comment: Is that because UN jobs don't have the requirement of being EU citizen or something?

Comment: @Aliweb: I don't know the details, but the UN has a very international workforce (intentionally), which also migrates at high rate, so they like have either an exemption from regulations regarding workers coming in from abroad, or large quotas.

Comment: @einpoklum in fact UN staff work under (semi-) diplomatic immunity, so there are no quotas, and the visas are free, and the application process is quick and painless.  The jobs are hard to get, however.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a job seeker site.

Answer (score 0):

Your question basically boils down to "How do I find a job in Switzerland". First of all, this is not a job help website. Secondly, having a good LinkedIN profile will definitely help your chances and there are plenty of jobs regularly updated on there. You could also check in the jobs section of Stack Overflow for anything relevant to your qualifications.

Obviously, a key fact that you should be aware of is to check if the employer is able to sponsor you for a work visa.Best of luck.